Jenkins: "Host key verification failed" when connecting to Git repository on JetBrains Space
I am trying to set up a Jenkins pipeline that clones a repository from JetBrains Space using SSH. However, I keep encountering the error "Host key verification failed." Here is the relevant part of my Jenkinsfile:
    pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        DOCKER_BUILDKIT = "1"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'space-ssh-key', keyFileVariable: 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY')]) {
                        sh '''
                            mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                            echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                            chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
                            git clone ssh://git@git.jetbrains.space/my-proj/main/my-rpoj.git .
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build Docker Images') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'chmod +x ./build/build-docker-images.kts'
                    sh './build/build-docker-images.kts'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy Application') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sshagent(['space-ssh-key']) {
                        sh '''
                            scp -r . ${env.DEPLOY_USER}@${env.DEPLOY_SERVER}:/var/www/app
                            ssh ${env.DEPLOY_USER}@${env.DEPLOY_SERVER} << EOF
                              cd /var/www/app
                              docker-compose down
                              docker-compose up -d
                            EOF
                        '''
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Despite adding the host key using ssh-keyscan, I still get the following error:
Failed to connect to repository: Command "git ls-remote -h -- ssh://git@git.jetbrains.space/myproj-dev/main/myproj.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: No RSA host key is known for git.jetbrains.space and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have verified that:
The SSH private key is correctly set in Jenkins.
The host key is added to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.
When I manually run the commands on the Jenkins server, they work fine. Here is what I've tried so far:
Manually adding the host key to ~/.ssh/known_hosts.
Including the ssh-keyscan step in the Jenkinsfile to add the host key.
What am I missing? How can I ensure that the host key verification passes in Jenkins?


When you run the commands manually, does the resulting line in ~/.ssh/known_hosts start with git.jetbrains.space ssh-rsa or something else?

Jenkins doesn't provide per job settings for git host key verification, you can only change it globally in Manage Jenkins -> Security -> Git Host Key Verification Configuration. Set it to Accept first connection.
Some advice you didn't ask for:

Checking ~/.ssh/known_hosts for the key is ambiguous because ~ evaluates to different values under different users. Check it for the user Jenkins runs as. You might be logged in as a different user, right?

ssh-keyscan in the pipeline is a bit too late, because Jenkins needs to connect to the git server to retrieve your pipeline.

SSH_PRIVATE_KEY holds the temp file name, not the key value. So echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa is not what you want, you are looking for cat "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa or cp "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Manual checkout with sh is rarely required, implicit checkout is perfectly fine in your pipeline.




Ensure Host Key is in known_hosts
The error indicates that the host key for git.jetbrains.space is not recognized by Jenkins. You need to ensure that the host key is correctly added to the ~/.ssh/known_hosts file for the Jenkins user.

Add SSH Key to Jenkins
Ensure that Jenkins has the correct SSH private key setup. You need to generate a public/private key pair for Jenkins and add the public key to your Git server, or add your private key to Jenkins.

Disable Strict Host Key Checking (Optional)
If you are still facing issues, you can try disabling strict host key checking by adding the following lines to your SSH configuration:


echo "Host *" > ~/.ssh/config
echo "    StrictHostKeyChecking no" >> ~/.ssh/config

all steps is completed and correct but no changes
